# Pass function to dynamic link library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, dll, function-pointers

I need to pass function inside dynamic link library project. In this project I have two functions:

```
HRESULT solve_serial(solver::TSolver_Setup &setup, solver::TSolver_Progress &progress) {
  start(setup.max_generations, setup.population_size, setup.problem_size, setup.lower_bound, setup.upper_bound);
}

void start(size_t problem_size, size_t max_generation, size_t population_size, const double* lower_bound, const double* upper_bound)
{
    while (t <= MaxGeneration)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            // ---------- HERE I NEED TO USE PASSED FUNCTION -------------
            f[i] = function(ffa[i]);  // obtain fitness of solution
            I[i] = f[i];                        // initialize attractiveness
        }
    }
}
```

`solve-serial` is called from external program and it will obtain `&setup` with function I need to pass inside funtion `start` where I will used it.

This is how `solver::TSolver_Setup` looks like:

```
using TObjective_Function = double(IfaceCalling*)(const void *data, const double *solution);

struct TSolver_Setup {
    const TObjective_Function objective;
};
```

How can I pass the funtion? I cannot change `solver::TSolver_Setup` but I can change `start` (or variables inside same file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, the problem you have is just about how to pass functions (or more precisely function pointers here) as argument and how to use them.

I understand that `setup` contains a pointer to a function called `objective`:

```
struct TSolver_Setup {
    const TObjective_Function objective;
    //....  (apparently a lot of other stuff you didn't talk about)
};
```

I understand also that you need to call this function in `start`(), in the line where you put a placeholder comment.  It's however not clear where the value should be stored, not which arguments should be used, so I'll use some assumptions and placeholders. Would you have access to `setup`, you could just do:

```
ffa[i] = setup.objective (&whatdata, &what solution);
```

But since you don't pass `setup` to `start()`, you'll have at least to pass the function to start by using an additional parameter `f`:

```
void start(size_t problem_size, size_t max_generation, size_t population_size, const double* lower_bound, const double* upper_bound, TObjective_Function f)
{
    ...
            ffa[i] = f (&whatdata, &what solution);// <---------- HERE IT IS ----------
    ...
}
```

ANd to pass the parameter, you just need to pass `objective`:

```
HRESULT solve_serial(solver::TSolver_Setup &setup, solver::TSolver_Progress &progress) {
  start(setup.max_generations, setup.population_size, setup.problem_size, setup.lower_bound, setup.upper_bound, setup.objective);
  return 0;  // you must return something !
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, let me know so that I adjust my answer.  But in this case you'd need first to clarify what your problem is exactly, what you have tried, and provide the missing elements that would allow us to repeat the problem.

Answer (score 0):

modify start function to include setup reference

```
void start(olver::TSolver_Setup &setup,.....)
```

call start :

```
start(setup,....
```

call function:

```
setup.objective(data,solution)
```